# jQuery.get the success parameter

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery.get to send a message to the server and it works.

I now want to action on the reply I get from jQuery.get and having no luck.

My simple test code to test it works is-

```
jQuery.get("/www", function(data){alert("it works");});
```

What do i have to be aware off to get the "success" to work

Comment: As I understand the docs, that _should_ work. Are you sure the the server is responding successfully?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if the *request* was successful or whatever was processed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up in path I think

```
jQuery.get("/www/some_script_file", function(data){alert("it should works");});
```

Comment: I tried your answer and no luck

As point of information I set up  a page of www on the server and to reply OK
In case the www was a problem I checked with another page still no luck